# Как ввести имя в начальный индекс массива?

Tags: java

Прошу подсказать, что я делаю не так? по коду все вроде понятно, но вылетает исключение! А хотелось что бы при вводе пользователя имени программа искала по массиву совпадения с именем, а затем выводила Имя(индекс 0) и Телефон (индекс 1) по массиву... если с консоли указывать то все норм работает, а вот с помощью `Scanner` не хочет :(

```
package javaapplication10;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication10 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
        String[] inp  = new String[0];
        String numbers [][] = {
            {"Tom", "555-3322"},
            {"Mary", "555-8976"},
            {"Jon", "555-1037"},
            {"Rachel", "555-1400"}           
        } ;

        int i;
        System.out.print("Введите Имя : ");
        inp[0] = myScanner.next(); 

        if(inp.length != 1) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java JavaApplication10 <name>");
        } else {
            for(i=0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                if(numbers[i][0].equals(inp[0])) {
                  System.out.println(numbers[i][0]+ ": " + numbers[i][1]);
                  break;
                }
            }

            if(i == numbers.length) {
                System.out.println("Name not found.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

вот ошибка:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Comment: код просто ад :)
исключение и ошибка разные вещи.
какое исключение вылетает? и зачем это? `if(inp.length != 1`

Comment: вот ошибка 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0'

Comment: if(inp.length != 1)  - для того что бы если вдруг пользователь введет больше индексовых значений то ответил ему пиши мол только одно имя

Comment: а почему код вам адом кажется? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В строке

```
String[] inp  = new String[0];
```

вы объявляете строковый массив `inp` размером 0. То есть в нем ничего не может быть.

Затем вы вычитываете с консоли введенное значение и кладете в массив:

```
inp[0] = myScanner.next();
```

Но у массива нет нулевого элемента, поскольку размер массива равен нулю. О чем и говорится в исключении `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`. Там же вы увидите и номер этой строки, спровоцировавшей исключение.

Соответственно строка

```
if (inp.length != 1)
```

бессмысленна, т.к. массив нулевой длины сам никогда не удлинится.

---

Вывод: объявите `inp` не как массив, а как обычную строку.

Comment: спасибо вам за наводку на мысль про нулевой элемент!!!! урааа!!!! получилось!!! нужно просто было объявить элемент массива inp не нулевой, а единицу! String[] inp  = new String[1];   спасибо еще раз огромное !!!